# jQuery format currency forcing 2 decimals

Tags: jquery, currency-formatting

It's a common pattern when entering a currency on touch devices to start entering the numbers, starting with the hundredths and forcing two decimal places, for example:

1. User types `1`, input formats it as `.01`
2. User then types `2`, input formats it as `.12`
3. User then types `3`, input formats it as `1.23`
4. User then types `4`, input formats it as `12.34`
5. User then types `5`, input formats it as `123.45`

...and so on. It would also be nice if it would insert commas when the number is < 999.99 (i.e. `1,000.00`).

I'm not sure what this pattern is even referred to as, so I haven't had much luck finding this functionality amongst the many already existing number formatting scripts.

Comment: [see here](http://cwestblog.com/2011/06/23/javascript-add-commas-to-numbers/)

Comment: Search for _jquery mask plugin_.

Comment: found this fiddle,  http://jsfiddle.net/77bMx/86/

Comment: @briansol That's the closest I've seen to what I'm looking for, thanks! I'll need to play around with it to get it to also insert commas for thousands separators.

Comment: Yeah, it needs some fine tuning for sure.  it's pretty raw and ugly and the cursor is quite misleading, as is trying to back-space out the placeholder 0.00.   But, the core functionality is in place.   Good luck.

Comment: Maybe you can link it with this plugin too:   http://www.bendewey.com/code/formatcurrency/demo/format_as_you_type.html